# Restart initial id of table with using MAX() method

Tags: database, db2

I am doing some changes on my table and I couldn't figure out the problem.
This is my SQL script;

```
ALTER TABLE X ALTER COLUMN X_ID RESTART WITH (SELECT MAX(X_ID) FROM X);
```

Altough I used `AS` instead of `WITH` and tried other combinations, I couldn't find the exact syntax. (By the way, I cannot set this property in the initialization, I got to do it after creation of the table )

Comment: MySql or SQL Server?

Comment: I am working on DB2, 
I am dividing the table into 2 different tables, after transferring datas, i have to restart the ID from one to maximum id of new table to prevent conflicts @Strawberry

Comment: @KemalToprakUçar Then tag it as [tag:DB2], not MySQL *and* SQL Server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When looking at the syntax for [ALTER TABLE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html) you will find that you can only use a constant, e.g., "RESTART WITH 12345". A query itself is not possible. For automation you would need to break it up, use a variable, generate the ALTER statement and execute it.

Comment: How would that look like?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is for DB2 for LUW, you can automate the process of resetting identity values with some dynamic SQL:

```
begin
 declare curmax bigint;
 for r as select tabschema, tabname, colname, nextcachefirstvalue, seqid 
          from syscat.colidentattributes where tabschema = current_schema
  do
   prepare s from 
    'select max(' || r.colname || ') from ' || 
     rtrim(r.tabschema) || '.' || r.tabname;
   begin
    declare c cursor for s;
    open c;
    fetch c into curmax;
    close c;
   end;
   if curmax >= r.nextcachefirstvalue
   then
    execute immediate 
     'alter table ' || rtrim(r.tabschema) || '.' || r.tabname ||
     ' alter column ' || r.colname || ' restart with ' || varchar(curmax+1);
   end if;
  end for;
end
```

You may need to change the data type of `curmax` if your identities are not integer, and adjust the query against `syscat.colidentattributes` to use the appropriate schema name.

Comment: I had issues, so might worth mentioning in order for this to work, your statement terminator must not be `;` I changed to `@` and it worked.
Thanks for sharing.