# How to make an IDENTITY `id` column to start with a different value?

Tags: db2, auto-increment, db2-luw

I have a DB2 table with an `id` column that has an auto increment, here's the code:

```
"id" BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1)
```

I manually inserted values that already have `id` values and do not begin with 1.
Now when I add records to this table, it begins at 1. I would like to begin when my records end., i.e. say the latest record has id 23, I would like the new record to have id = 24.

Is there a way I can do this on all my tables with minimum effort?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32969802/1227152

Comment: https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/sqlp/rbafymst79.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @mustaccio comment, the most straightforward to achieve it is:

```
ALTER TABLE "tableName" ALTER COLUMN "columnName" RESTART WITH <new index value>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
db2 alter table <table_name> alter column <column_name> drop identity
```

and

```
db2 alter table <table_name> alter column <column_name> set generated always as identity (start with <max(column_identity_name)>)
```

-

```
user@host:/home/db2inst1:>db2 "CREATE TABLE TEST (ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1),    NAME CHAR(6))"

insert into test (NAME) VALUES ('test1')"
insert into test (NAME) VALUES ('test2')"
insert into test (NAME) VALUES ('test3')"
insert into test (NAME) VALUES ('test4')"
insert into test (NAME) VALUES ('test5')"
insert into test (NAME) VALUES ('test6')"
insert into test (NAME) VALUES ('test7')"
insert into test (ID,NAME) VALUES (4,'test8')"
insert into test (ID,NAME) VALUES (4,'test9')"
insert into test (ID,NAME) VALUES (4,'test10')"
insert into test (ID,NAME) VALUES (4,'test11')"
insert into test (ID,NAME) VALUES (4,'test12')"
insert into test (ID,NAME) VALUES (2,'test13')"
insert into test (ID,NAME) VALUES (2,'test14')"
insert into test (ID,NAME) VALUES (2,'test15')"
insert into test (ID,NAME) VALUES (3,'test16')"
insert into test (NAME) VALUES ('test17')"
insert into test (NAME) VALUES ('test18')"
insert into test (NAME) VALUES ('test19')"
insert into test (NAME) VALUES ('test20')"
insert into test (NAME) VALUES ('test21')"
insert into test (NAME) VALUES ('test22')"
insert into test (NAME) VALUES ('test23')"
insert into test (NAME) VALUES ('test24')"
```

-

```
user@host:/home/db2inst1:>db2 "select row_number() over (order by ID) as ROWID,ID,NAME from test"


                ID                   NAME  
-------------------- -------------------- ------
                   1                    1 test1 
                   2                    2 test2 
                   3                    2 test13
                   4                    2 test14
                   5                    2 test15
                   6                    3 test3 
                   7                    3 test16
                   8                    4 test4 
                   9                    4 test8 
                  10                    4 test9 
                  11                    4 test10
                  12                    4 test11
                  13                    4 test12
                  14                    5 test5 
                  15                    6 test6 
                  16                    7 test7 
                  17                    8 test17
                  18                    9 test18
                  19                   10 test19
                  20                   11 test20
                  21                   12 test21
                  22                   13 test22
                  23                   14 test23
                  24                   15 test24

  24 record(s) selected.

user@host:/home/db2inst1:>db2 alter table test alter column id drop identity
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

I found start value from max row_number;

```
user@host:/home/db2inst1:>db2 "alter table test alter column id set generated always as identity (start with 25)"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
insert into test (NAME) VALUES ('test25')"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
user@host:/home/db2inst1:>db2 "select row_number() over (order by ID) as ROWID,ID,NAME from test"

ROWID                ID                   NAME  
-------------------- -------------------- ------
                   1                    1 test1 
                   2                    2 test2 
                   3                    2 test13
                   4                    2 test14
                   5                    2 test15
                   6                    3 test3 
                   7                    3 test16
                   8                    4 test4 
                   9                    4 test8 
                  10                    4 test9 
                  11                    4 test10
                  12                    4 test11
                  13                    4 test12
                  14                    5 test5 
                  15                    6 test6 
                  16                    7 test7 
                  17                    8 test17
                  18                    9 test18
                  19                   10 test19
                  20                   11 test20
                  21                   12 test21
                  22                   13 test22
                  23                   14 test23
                  24                   15 test24
                  25                   25 test25

  25 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: You don't need to drop the identity, you can simply `RESTART` it.

Comment: what I needed are the two first lines of your answer. Maybe edit your answer to reflect mustaccio comment?